# Realitykit feature crashes on ios 13.4.1 but works in 15.2

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I have project with deployment target 10+ with a realitykit feature that only appears on ios 13+ devices , the problem is it runs successfully in real device with ios 15.2 but crashes in ios 13.4.1 with error

> Instantiating class metadata for class with missing weak-linked ancestor

```
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, *)
class MyVC: UIViewController, ARCoachingOverlayViewDelegate {

    func addModel() { 

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Matrix", ofType: "usdz")! 
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) 
        let assetsLoader = try Entity.load(contentsOf: url)// crashes here
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal) 
        anchor.addChild(assetsLoader) 
        arView.scene.anchors.removeAll() 
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor) 
        .....
   }
   ....
}


// instantiating class metadata for class with missing weak-linked ancestor(lldb)
```

Where **Matrix.usdz** exists in bundle with target membership ticked

I have read this [Instantiating class metadata for class with missing weak-linked ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67742274/instantiating-class-metadata-for-class-with-missing-weak-linked-ancestor) but it doesn't help

**BTW if i raised deployment target to ios 13 it works well with any
13+ version**